# MacTeX installation, non-functioning TeXShop

Tags: installing, mac

I used the MacTeX installation on a new MacBookPro and I find the folder `/usr/texbin` empty and the functionality not there, error message

> "Can't find required tool."
>
> "usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist".

Can't find `pdflatex` anywhere else either.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what you did? Which program did you start? From where was this programm? Downloaded from ...?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I upgraded to Mavericks and then again to Yosemite. I found that the `/usr/` folder had an alias for `/texbin` but that alias did not lead anywhere. This was resolved by allowing Read Only access to the `local` folder in `usr` for my user account. Perhaps the following would help:

Try going to `/usr/` using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> in Finder and allowing Read Only access to the `local` folder there. This can be done by using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to access folder Properties of `local`, and then adding your user account with Read Only access.